# Windows batch job through RDP, possible?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I saw a "Log on as Batch job" option in GPO, so I think this feature might be available.

I would like to logon to multiple machine, execute a cmd or powershell script on the machine locally. Just like how you do that with SSH.

Any ideas? It's best that I don't need to install additional software on each server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't involve RDP.  Either Powershell itself, quite a few native command line utilities typically support `/S <computername>` or [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) will handle 99% of what you need to do remotely.